# postgresql import csv file

Tags: database, postgresql

I need upload a csv file to postgresql database table.
the csv file like

```
A           B               C       D               E       F

16777216    16777471        AU      AUSTRALIA       OC      OCEANIA
16777472    16778239        CN      CHINA           AS      ASIA
16778240    16779263        AU      AUSTRALIA       OC      OCEANIA
16779264    16781311        CN      CHINA           AS      ASIA
```

and the table is

```
CREATE TABLE ipligence
(
  ip_from numeric(11,0) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  ip_to numeric(11,0) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  country_code character varying(10)[] NOT NULL,
  country_name character varying(225)[] NOT NULL,
  continent_code character varying(10)[] NOT NULL,
  continent_name character varying(255)[] NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT ipligence_pkey PRIMARY KEY (ip_to )
 )
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
 );
ALTER TABLE ipligence
```

and i use copy command in pgsql,

```
copy ipligence 
from '/home/pgsql/ipligence-lite.csv' 
delimiter as ',' 
csv quote as '"';
```

but it shows

```
  ERROR:  array value must start with "{" or dimension information
  CONTEXT:  COPY ipligence, line 1, column country_code: "AU"
```

how can i successfully input csv file into postgresql database. Thanks!

Comment: Why are you trying to use varchar arrays for the country and continent columns in your table?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your table is created incorrectly.  For example, this column declaration:

```
country_code character varying(10)[] NOT NULL,
```

is creating an array of varchar(10).  You only want one.  Drop the `[]` on those columns.

Also, the sample data you posted is not actually comma-separated, but I'm assuming that the actual data file is.